# Special polynomials having atleast one root on the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

I have the following problem: For each $w\in\mathbb{T},$ ($\mathbb{T}$ denotes the unit circle), consider the polynomial $P_{w,n}(z)=z^{n+1}+z^n-2w$ of degree $n+1,$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Does there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the above polynomial has atleast one root on the unit circle for each $w\in\mathbb{T}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we have

$$\lvert z^{n+1} + z^n\rvert = \lvert z+1\rvert\cdot \lvert z\rvert^n = \lvert z+1\rvert$$

on the unit circle. For $w \in \mathbb{T}$, we have $\lvert 2w\rvert = 2$, so the only point of the unit circle that can possibly be a zero of

$$P_{w,n}(z) = z^{n+1} + z^n - 2w$$

is $z = 1$, and that is a zero only for $w = 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, that was quite simple. Thanks.